# noscript tag - PHP tracker does not trigger as source in image

Tags: javascript, html, tracking, noscript

I searched but I could not find anything that suits my problem.

I have a JavaScript which gathers some information and then sends it to a PHP file. Now I'm trying to call the PHP file directly if the visitor has JS disabled.

This is in between `<body>` and `</body>`.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = 4;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.org/tracking.js"></script>
<noscript><img src="http://www.example.org/tracking.php?id=4&nojs=true" ></noscript>
```

I turn of my JS in my browser, visit the site and I see a call to tracking.php
But... during the day, my 80 visitors have not even once called tracking.php.
I have looked at my Apache access log and the only one accessing tracking.php is me.

Do you guys have any suggestions or examples on why my visitors, who have JS disabled, does not communicate with the noscript file? Is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know they have JS disabled?

Comment: Do you know they are real visitors? And not bots that don't request images or scripts?

Comment: Hi Niet and Quentin!
In the top of the php file that the JS file is talking to, there is a log. That log has not been activated.
In the top of the noscript php file, there is a log, and it has not been activated.

This makes me think that they do not have JS activated. But I have not done any test to see if they have images activated. I will do some tests and come back.

Comment: Image tracker activated. If they could load picture they will load a php file (with image/png header) and a log will write down their IP.

Comment: Okey I got one hit now. He could load the image. He did not get in touch with my JS tracker. So whats left? Well the notag tracker. Which he did not get in touch with! How is this possible??